# Outer glow in edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I'm trying to make outer grow in edit text view for better look for user experience.
[image]
I tried some of the method to get this result. On of the example is:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:shadowColor="#003399"
        android:shadowDx="0"
        android:shadowDy="0" 
        android:shadowRadius="3">
```

But it didn't give the result. Is their any other effective way or i just have to give up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this with 9 path drawing tool. [Link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch)

Answer (score 0):

try this

create a new xml file named borderr.xml in drawable folder and put this in it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#1E90FF" />


    <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#1E90FF" />
</shape>
```

and on button set

```
 android:background="@drawable/borderr"
```

Comment: ok. Try to use 9-Patch drawables and then set background of the EDITTEXT.