# How to glow effect behind the edit text like in the image?

Tags: android

[image]

I am trying to get a glow effect like the background for `edittext`

I tried doing it but the background is not as much effective as the image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#68F30606"/>
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item
        android:left="1.7dp"
        android:right="1.7dp"
        android:top="1.7dp"
        android:bottom="1.7dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Can someone help me to solve this mystery?

Comment: This glow used to be in old android phones. Are you sure you want to add it?

Comment: @TaraIordanov yes I want it

Comment: well, check my answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you will need to use the old-technique(kind of) of 9-Patch Drawing. I used to do it too. Examples are scarce because they are big, but there is documentation.

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.

Also, if this helps you can check this too: [Outer glow in edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136405/outer-glow-in-edittext)

To use the 9-Patch images in Xml to this (remember this is after you have created the 9-Patch Images):

1. Reference the drawable with the name but don't include .9.png (auto-complete in eclipse will take care of this)
2. Make sure you only have 1 image under the main /drawable folder (not a version for each dpi folder)
3. The image must be specified using :background, not :src *(this got me stuck for a while)*

   `android:background="@drawable/splash_logo"`
4. Make sure the image and layout that contains it are using:

   `android:layout_width="fill_parent"

   android:layout_height="fill_parent"`

Credit To: [Creating & Using 9-patch images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124719/creating-using-9-patch-images-in-android)

Also, check this website out, it contains a lot of useful examples that the documentation doesn't provide:
https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-9-patch-image-files

Comment: lordanov Now I know that 9 patch tools will help, but how does 9 patch tool can be applicable for an XML file. I mean drawable I mentioned above or I should create an image and make text appear on edit text